# Spring Data JPA @Query passing string to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am utilising Spring Data JPA and am getting some strange behaviour that I cannot work out how to fix.

```
 @Query(value="EXEC dbo.spChartPracticeInternalDoctor ?, ?, ?, ?", nativeQuery = true)
List<ReportDataSet> spChartPracticeInternalDoctor(Long id, String date,Long months, String tests);
```

When I pass in a CSV string in tests that contains no spaces the stored procedure executes correctly ( i.e. SC,ECG )

But when I pass in a tests string with a space it errors.

e.g.  SC,ECG,IP Standard Consult

```
2018-04-12 12:45:13.309 DEBUG 684 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] com.pci.dprm.aop.logging.LoggingAspect   : Enter: com.pci.dprm.web.rest.ReportDataSetResource.spChartPracticeInternalDoctor() with argument[s] = [36, 2018-04-12T12:05:01 08:00, 24, SC,ECG,IP Standard Consult]
Hibernate: EXEC dbo.spChartPracticeInternalDoctor ?, ?, ?, ?
2018-04-12 12:45:13.316  WARN 684 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 8114, SQLState: S0001
2018-04-12 12:45:13.317 ERROR 684 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Error converting data type nvarchar to date.
```

It seems that hibernate is not escaping the string correctly when passing it to SQL, but I cannot work out how to overwrite the escaping.

I would appreciate any ideas to deal with this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think error is not because of 4th parameter it is because of 2nd parameter. Logs shows that --> Error converting data type nvarchar to date.

I think you need to convert second argument to Date. 
Please see below code snippet for your reference.

```
@Query(value="EXEC dbo.spChartPracticeInternalDoctor ?, ?, ?, ?", nativeQuery = true)
List<ReportDataSet> spChartPracticeInternalDoctor(Long id, Date date,Long months, String tests);
```

Comment: Its still a mystery to my why this only occurred when a parameter with a space in it was used. But changing it to LocalDate solved the issue. Thanks